# Cygwin - command not found

Tags: path, cygwin, ls

Running bash commands in cygwin produce the following error:

```
$ ls
ls: command not found
```

This is a question that I self-answered on my tech blog where I keep the tech-tips which I need to give to myself from time to time, so I decided to move it over here instead. The original blog post is here: http://thehacklist.blogspot.com/2009/04/cygwin-ls-command-not-found.html

If you are a linux enthusiast and really miss those greps and sed/awks on the windows box, you've probably installed [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). You tried running it either by double-clicking the cygwin icon on your desktop or the `cygwin.bat` file in your `C:\cygwin` directory and got the `bash-3.X$` prompt. However, although the `pwd` or `cd` commands work, if you try `ls`, it says:`ls: command not found`.

Comment: Well, `pwd` and `cd` are builtins in bash, so it does not make sense to compare them to `ls`.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

1. Right click on "My Computer" -> Properties -> Advanced ->
   Environment Variables
2. Add a new environment variable, called `CYGWIN_HOME` and set its value to `C:\cygwin`
3. Edit the PATH environment variable and add `%CYGWIN_HOME%\bin` to it (usually separated by a ';').
4. Just click okay, exit any command prompts or bash shells (over cygwin) you may have open, and open it again - it'll work!

Assumption - this assumes that you have installed cygwin at `C:\cygwin`. If you've kept it someplace else, please modify the above accordingly.

Comment: didn't work for me

Comment: It works! @Raindrop be sure you followed instructions and closed all opened consoles. If you use guake style console, go to menu->File->Exit.

Comment: doesn't work for me either

Comment: Possibly doesn't work for some people because they installed Cygwin elsewhere. If you have a 64-bit OS, your Cygwin path may be `C:\cygwin64`.

Comment: Doesn't work, fantastic.

Comment: does not work on windows 8 - 32bits,  @michael_n solutions works adding "C:\cygwin\bin;C:\cygwin;" to PATH in environment variables

Comment: @stackdave thx. I add the two path to the enviroment and it works.

Comment: not working w10

Comment: worked flawlessly! tail command wasn't working before adding "CYGWIN_HOME" environment variable.

Comment: This did not work for me. I wanted to post a solution that works for me but the question is closed. Great.
This happened to me after an update. Simply re-creating the shortcut solved the problem for me.

Comment: That's a "bad" idea - some GNU commands have the same name as the DOS ones - mixing the WIN32 paths with Cygwin ones will break .bat files

Comment: I think that step 3. could be "Edit the PATH environment variable and add `%CYGWIN_HOME%\bin` to it (usually separated by a ';')."

Answer (score 16):

Check the cygwin.bat file, it should have something like:

```
set PATH=C:\cygwin\bin;C:\cygwin;%PATH%
...etc
bash --login -i
```

(you don't really need c:\cygwin in there, but I have some additional scripts/bat files there; the key thing is c:\cygwin\bin)

Comment: this worked for me on windows 8 , 32 bits

Comment: For me at least, it's now C:\cygwin64\bin\

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone want to do the same thing as approved answer in PowerShell:

```
 [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path', $Env:Path + "C:\cygwin64\bin;", 'User')
```

- Here I'm on Windows 11 so my Cygwin path have 64 in the name (C:\cygwin**64**\bin).
- I used scope `'User'` but if you want to set it globally you should run PowerShell as Admin and use scope `'Machine'`
- I'm putting `;` at the end because my $Env:Path ends with it. If it's different for you use `$Env:Path + ";C:\cygwin64\bin"`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by adding `C:\cygwin\bin` to the *Windows* path.

Maybe not suitable for every use-case but got the job done in my situation.