# ls and cd commands not working with Cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin

I am trying to use Cygwin to run my first python program. I downloaded python and Cygwin. Within the Cygwin terminal I ran the command: "which python" to confirm that the terminal could find python. However when I attempt to cd into my Desktop for example, I get "-bash: cd: Desktop: No such file or directory". When I try to do an ls, it simply returns an empty line. For some reason "pwd" works normally.

I am having a problem similar to the one here: [Cygwin ls command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797194/cygwin-ls-command-not-found)

However changing the environmental variables has no effect (even after I closed and repopened the terminal window).

Comment: basically the folder than contains ls command has to be in the Environment Variables. What happens when you manually search 'ls' command binary and add the parent folder to environmental variables?

Comment: It sounds like you're in an empty directory. What does `pwd` print, and what do you see when you look in that folder in the GUI?

Comment: your Cygwin home directory is usually NOT the Windows user directory. `cygpath -w ~` should show something like `c:\cgwin64\home\your_user_name`

Comment: About python, you need to install it: https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.setup.what-packages. As default only ~50 packages are installed, while 4000 package are eventually available

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `C:\cygwin64\bin` or its equivalent is set as a path variable.

Run mintty.exe as administrator and enter: `mkpasswd -l -p "$(cygpath -H)" > /etc/passwd`

Close mintty.exe and access it again through the Windows shortcut '**Cygwin64 Terminal**'. This is auto-generated during setup. The shortcut target should be set as the path to the bin which contains mintty.exe `C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: this suggestion is usually obsolete. https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-mapping-nsswitch

Comment: Yes, this was the only workaround which seemed to work unfortunately. I am new to cygwin to so there is probably something I am missing in terms of domain knowledge.